# WPF Nested UserControl Datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 classes (InnerModel and OuterModel). OuterModel contains 2 InnerModel instances. I would like to create UserControls for them (InnerUserControl and OuterUserControl). OuterUserControl contains 2 InnerUserControls. But I can't figure out how to make binding works in this case.
Below is the complete code of what I try to do.
Please advise how to fix it to get the same result as on a pic at the end.
Thanks in advance!

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
<Window x:Class="NestedUserControl.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NestedUserControl"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="450">
<Grid>
    <local:OuterUserControl x:Name="test"/>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var model = new OuterModel("TEST1", "TEST2");
        test.DataContext = model;
    }
}
```

**InnerModel.cs**

```
public class InnerModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public String Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }
    private string data;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public InnerModel(string _data) => data = _data;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
}
```

**InnerUserControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="NestedUserControl.InnerUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NestedUserControl"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="450">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Data}"/>
</Grid>
```

**InnerUserControl.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class InnerUserControl : UserControl
{
    public InnerUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**OuterModel.cs**

```
public class OuterModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public InnerModel model1;
    public InnerModel model2;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public OuterModel(string data1, string data2)
    {
        model1 = new InnerModel(data1);
        model2 = new InnerModel(data2);
    }
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
}
```

**OuterUserControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="NestedUserControl.OuterUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NestedUserControl"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="450">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <local:InnerUserControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="inner1" DataContext="model1"/>
    <local:InnerUserControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="inner2" DataContext="model2"/>
</Grid>
```

**OuerUserControl.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class OuterUserControl : UserControl
{
    public OuterUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

[Working binding MainWindow.xaml.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23nXJ.png)

Comment: easiest would be to add inside your OuterModel two new properties for inner controls and they would bound to those

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

Two problems here, first of all your inner models need to be properties, so change their declarations to this:

```
public InnerModel model1 {get; set;}
public InnerModel model2 {get; set;}
```

Second problem is with your bindings, you need to do this instead:

```
<local:InnerUserControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="inner1" DataContext="{Binding model1}"/>
<local:InnerUserControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="inner2" DataContext="{Binding model2}"/>
```

Comment: This will not fix the problem.  And user controls already "inherit" the data context of the containing control like the Window for example

Comment: SO specifically said he wants the InnerUserControls bound to the InnerModel instances.

Comment: Thanks, Mark! That's exactly what I've been looking for. I agree with you that dependency properties looks bulky. That was the point why I was looking for some xaml solution.

Comment: @Kirill glad to help. Just remember that if you subsequently want to re-assign those properties, and have your view update to reflect that change, then they will need to support [property change notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification). Good luck!